# MSBuild error Could not load the Visual C++ component while installing node

Tags: node.js, windows, npm-install

I'm trying to run `npm install` into a subfolder but I keep getting a following error:

> msbuild : error msb3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component

I have Visual Studio Code and the .NET framework installed on my machine so I'm not sure how to get around this error. Any advice would be appreciated.

Running Microsoft 7 Professional

Comment: Visual Studio Code does not include a C++ compiler.  One or more of the modules has a native compliation requirement.  You can install the VC++ build tools free from Microsoft to provide a compiler

Comment: Hi Joe - do you have a link to the build tools?

Comment: https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compile native Node modules on Windows try to install these build tools.

Start PowerShell or cmd as Administrator and run:

```
npm install --global windows-build-tools
```

Or, if you are using Yarn:

```
yarn global add windows-build-tools
```

P.S.[Windows Vista / 7 only] requires .NET Framework 4.5.1

I hope it helps